# Problem on divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a small problem on divisibility which I would like to share for the proof.

If $n$ divides $a^m$ $-1$, and $n-1$ is multiple of $m$, then $n$  divides $a^{n-1}$ $-1$.

How is the statement true?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please consider updating your question with some information about what you have tried or where you are getting stuck. You will find people are much more willing to help if you do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we can write $n-1=b\cdot m$ where $b$ is some integer

As $\displaystyle a^m\equiv1\pmod n\implies a^{b\cdot m}\equiv1^b\pmod n\equiv1\implies a^{n-1}\equiv1\pmod n$

Answer (score 3):

This follows from the fact that if $a$ divides $b-1$, then $a$ divides $b^k-1$, since $b-1$ divides $b^k-1$.

Answer (score 0):

$a^{n-1}-1=a^{km}-1=\left(a^{m}-1\right)\left(a^{\left(k-1\right)m}+a^{\left(k-2\right)m}+\cdots a^{m}+1\right)$
so divisors of factor $a^{m}-1$ are divisors of $a^{n-1}-1$